# Connecting Firebase to Unity for simple Log In

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebasesimplelogin

I am trying to create a simple log in using unity, I have connected it to firebase but not sure how to populate the database in firebase? I have created a simple GUI but need to link it to firebase so every time I enter text it can populate the database?

Comment: Have a look at this demo project: https://github.com/benwulfe/FireShooter

Comment: Hi thanks for that , but I'm struggling to understand the code within each of the firebase scripts as it seems in depth. Anything else you would recommend ?

Comment: It's based on this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial . But recommendations like that are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Search for "Unity Tutorial" and you'll find dozens/hundreds more.